# Retrieving Data back into a form in excel vba

Tags: excel, forms

I am pretty new to VBA in Excel. I have built a form which users enter data and at the press of a button it drops all that data into an excel spreadsheet and clears the form. What i need now is code for the user to push a button (off a list or combo box that shows already entered data) and have that data be brought back into the form for changes. I am trying to keep them out of the spreadsheet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think must be like this:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Change()
Worksheets("worksheetname").Activate
TextBox1 = Cells(1,1).Text
End Sub
```

In "Cells()" you have to selecet the specific cell which contains the value. But if you want to use excel as a kind of a database you should think about if it's the right tool, maybe access would be better.